# Does the system record the exception when a .NET service fails?

Tags: c#, .net, crash, windows-services

I have a .NET4/C# based windows service running on Windows Server 2008 R2 x64.  Rarely it crashes and none of the catch blocks get triggered (they are in all root methods).  I would like to know why.

Does the system record somewhere the error that it fails with?

Comment: Writing an event handler for AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException is your job, Windows doesn't do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to see something in EventViewer->Windows Logs. Here you can find which kind of data EventViewer is tracking:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-information-event-logs-event-viewer#1TC=windows-7